# CORS no reconoce la direccion IP de mi frontend

Tags: nodejs, angular, cors

Tengo un problema con Cors en mi backend, Cors indica que la dirección ip que coloque en la lista blanca no es igual a la que usa mi frontend.

Esto es el servicio que envía los datos al backend:

```html
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Persona } from '../modelos/persona';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, tap, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import {HttpClient,HttpErrorResponse,HttpHeaders }from '@angular/common/http'

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class PersonaService {

  headers=new HttpHeaders();

  selectedPersona: Persona;
  personas:Persona[];
  readonly URL_API='http://localhost:3000/Inicio/Persona';
  
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { 
    this.selectedPersona=new Persona();
  }

  postPersona(persona:Persona){
    return this.http.post(this.URL_API,persona)
  }
```

La petición llega desde http://209.145.52.133:8080 que es mi front

En mi Backend establezco la direccion permitida :

```html
app.use(cors({origin:'http://209.145.52.133:8080'}));
```

Y al final devuelve el error :

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3000/Inicio/Login' from
> origin 'http://209.145.52.133:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value
> 'http://209.145.52.133/' that is not equal to the supplied origin.

Comment: Parece que te sobra el puerto, ¿has probado eliminándolo de la configuración?

Comment: Como dice @PabloLozano, debes eliminar el puerto del *origin*: `http://209.145.52.133/`.